# An application is not detecting a "Powershell coded" key stroke

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

So far am only using this line of PowerShell code which i got after googling around:

```
  [System.windows.forms.sendkeys]::Sendwait('{INSERT}')
```

to mimic the pressing of the ***INSERT*** key which is a global shortcut assigned for an overclocking profile which i created in MSI afterBruner application.

The code works fine **inside** the powershell editor (i see the blinker style changes) but without the Afterburner noticing it.
On the other hand ,if i run the code by using the method ( Rightclick + run ) i get this error

```
Unable to find type [System.windows.forms.sendkeys].
At D:\openhardwaremonitor-v0.8.0-beta\checkrig - Copy.ps1:57 char:6
+      [System.windows.forms.sendkeys]::Sendwait('{INSERT}')
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: 
(System.windows.forms.sendkeys:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Any suggestions?thanks!.

P.S
Physically pressing the INSERT key works just fine,even if am pressing it while am inside the Powershell editor.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an event setup to verify if this works but my guess is you need to load the assembly before calling it.  Just add

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

to the first line of the script.  The ISE sometimes does some setup for you that the shell does not.

Comment: loading the assembly fixed the error i was getting when running the code from the outside,but still MSI afterburner not reacting to the INSERT stroke  generated from the code.